# SOLVED: GL context doesn't create any new GL objects after MotionEvent

Tags: android, opengl-es, java-native-interface, glsurfaceview

I implement a native JNI C++ OpenGL ES3, I created the `GLSurfaceView` on Java and everything works fine until I start handle Motion events. In C++ all new GL object creations doesn't work like `glBindVertexArray(VAO);` it never changes the VAO default value.

I wonder if the GL context lost focus or changed so I have to use `eglMakeCurrent`? if yes how to do that in native?

this is how I handle `MotionEvent` between Java and C++:

// I override GLSurfaceView onTouchEvent

```
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        ActivityMain.onTouch(event);
        return true;
    }
}
```

the `ActivityMain.onTouch(event);` is a native method that sends the Motion event to native environment and read some data, this is the native method

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_game_ActivityMain_onTouch(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass obj,jobject motionEvent) {
    jclass motionEventClass=jenv->GetObjectClass(motionEvent);

    jmethodID pointersCountMethodId = jenv->GetMethodID(motionEventClass,"getPointerCount", "()I");
    int pointersCount = jenv->CallIntMethod(motionEvent, pointersCountMethodId);
    jmethodID getActionMethodId = jenv->GetMethodID(motionEventClass, "getAction", "()I");
    int32_t action = jenv->CallIntMethod(motionEvent, getActionMethodId);

    jmethodID getXMethodId = jenv->GetMethodID(motionEventClass, "getX", "(I)F");
    float x0 = jenv->CallFloatMethod(motionEvent, getXMethodId,0);

    jmethodID getYMethodId = jenv->GetMethodID(motionEventClass, "getY", "(I)F");
    float y0 = jenv->CallFloatMethod(motionEvent, getYMethodId,0);

    float x1=0;
    float y1=0;
    if(pointersCount>1){
        x1 = jenv->CallFloatMethod(motionEvent, getXMethodId,1);
        y1 = jenv->CallFloatMethod(motionEvent, getYMethodId,1);
    }

    States::MotionEvent inputEvent;
    inputEvent.PointersCount=pointersCount;
    inputEvent.Action=action;
    inputEvent.X0=x0;
    inputEvent.Y0=y0;
    inputEvent.X1=x1;
    inputEvent.Y1=y1;
    game->OnMotionEvent(inputEvent);
}
```

Edit: Solution

I have just replaced `OnTouchEvent` with this

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
    queueEvent(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            ActivityMain.onTouch(event);
        }});
    return true;
}
```

Now it works good. but I don't understand the reason. any ideas?